# Crash on ip nat outside/inside

Tags: cisco, nat, internet

I just bought my first cisco gear and learning how to use it. Right now i want to configure nat but it keeps crashing my router. It stays on, but no commands work anymore.

```
ArborMain(config-if)#ip nat outside

*Oct 19 17:25:01.635: %LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface NVI0, changed state to up

% PDL Error : Failed to compile regexp
   File : skype.pdl
   Line : 73
        : (field non-char (regexp 
                              ^^^^^^^


% PDL Error : Failed to compile regexp
   File : skype.pdl
   Line : 520
        : (field tcp-non-char (regexp `.*(^@|^A|^B|^C|^D|^E|^F|·|·|·|
|^K|^L|
|^N|^O|
                                  ^^^^^^^

% NBAR Error : Activation failed due to insufficient dynamic memory
% NBAR Error: Stile could not add protocol node  
%NAT: Error activating CNBAR on the interface FastEthernet0/0
ArborMain(config-if)#
*Oct 19 17:25:05.375: %SYS-2-MALLOCFAIL: Memory allocation of 10260 bytes failed from 0x621F1574, alignment 0 
Pool: Processor  Free: 9476  Cause: Not enough free memory 
Alternate Pool: None  Free: 0  Cause: No Alternate pool 
-Process= "Exec", ipl= 0, pid= 3,  -Traceback= 0x6029C62Cz 0x602B55B0z 0x631587CCz 0x621F0D1Cz 0x621F5AE0z 0x621F2938z 0x621F3120z 0x621F47A4z 0x621F5114z 0x6245290Cz 0x62452BECz 0x62452D14z 0x62452D14z 0x6245406Cz 0x6248E0B8z 0x62498F0Cz
*Oct 19 17:25:05.543: %NBAR-2-NOMEMORY: No memory available for StILE lmalloc,  -Traceback= 0x62479728z 0x62479864z 0x6247DAD0z 0x6247DB28z 0x6247DB28z 0x6247DE10z 0x6247F1DCz 0x6248E1A8z 0x62498F0Cz 0x6248525Cz 0x624A46ECz 0x624A4A84z 0x61716774z 0x61718ACCz 0x60F8C87Cz 0x60FB2904z
ArborMain(config-if)#
```

This is what happens. I am no expert so please don't hate. I just need some help. 
Thanks in advance!!

EDIT: Router is cisco 1841 and image is ADVENTERPRISEK9

Comment: Is this new genuine equipment, or something you got second hand?  I haven't seen that error before.  Are you sure you have sufficient memory in the router for the software image you are running?

Comment: second hand. Ram I don't know, and running ADVENTERPRISEK9. The last one is probably the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error messages like `insufficient dynamic memory` and `Not enough free memory` are quite clear: the router simply does not have enough memory (RAM) to run NAT in addition to all the features that you already have enabled.

So this means that you have a few options:

- Add more physical RAM
- Depending on what IOS version you are running, consider a downgrade to a less memory demanding version (e.g. 12.4 will consume less memory than 12.4T or 15.1M). Downside is of course that you may also loose some functionality.
- Downgrade from Advanced Enterprise (which is the top-end feature set, but so very memory hungry) to a less memory consuming feature set, e.g. you can run "IP BASE W/O CRYPTO" on a 1841 with 128MB RAM and still run 15.1(4)M.
- Disable some of the features that you currently have enabled, e.g. NBAR. (Note that I'm just mentioning NBAR because I can tell from the output that you have it enabled; you may just as well disable other features, although NBAR might be one of the more memory hungry ones).
- Any combination of the above

It really depends on what you want (which features and sub-features you require), and of course if you can legally obtain another image.

Cisco's [Software Research](https://software.cisco.com/selection/research.html) tool may help you determine which IOS version and feature set you can run with your amount of RAM, or vice versa how many RAM you need to run a certain image.